# Correct usage of storing objects in maps

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

Say I need to store a collection of Student objects and each student has a unique id. One option is to store all of them in a list, but then when searching for a student, I'd have to perform a linear search and check their id's. The other option would be to use a map, of something like: Map where the keys are the student id's that map to the actual student objects.

Is this a sensible approach for the given problem? On the one hand it feels right because I can easily retrieve a student by their id, however, on the other hand, it feels like I'm slightly redundantly storing the id, which already exists within the student object - so I'm sort of storing it twice, but the key is the lookup mechanism.

My add would be something like:

```
public void add(Student s) {
     lookup.put(s.getId(), s);
}
```

Comment: That's what I do. You can also implement the equals() and hashCode methods on your student object

Comment: data structures are not about feelings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this redundancy be the only one you will ever encounter in programming.

The added value of using Map with unique object id, in terms of both performance and readability, is worth the small overhead incurred by such practice.

If you really feel this overhead is too much, the objects you put inside your Map data structure can be stripped of the ID property, and the ID property will only be used as the key, than, during retrieval, you can infer the ID from the map key.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real **correct** usage in this case. You need to consider what you are going to do with this collection once you have finished building it. Are you going to iterate over it? Are you going to want to sort it?

It is certainly possible to create a `Map` that automatically pulls the key out of the value but, again, there is a limit to the usefullness of this structure as iterating or sorting may become more difficult.

Here is a `CurriedHashMap` that kind of does what you are considering. Ignore the fact that it is using `HashMap` functionality under the hood.

```
class CurriedHashMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {

    /**
     * Function that extracts key from value.
     */
    final Function<V, K> curry;

    public CurriedHashMap(Function<V, K> curry) {
        this.curry = curry;
    }

    /**
     * One-value put - the key is intuited from the value using the `curry` function.
     */
    public V put(V value) {
        return super.put(curry.apply(value), value);
    }

}
```